# macOS `ps` gives bundle identifier instead of path for some XPC services

Tags: macos, xpc, launch-services

My macOS app can launch a faceless helper application which is shipped in its `Contents/Library/LoginItems` using Apple's Service Management Framework, as described in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW5-SW1).  Funny thing is, when I request the unix `ps` program to give me the command/paths, for this helper process, it gives the bundle identifier instead.  Example:

```
jk$ ps -x -o command
...
com.mycompany.MyAgent
...
```

It gives me the same answer with or without the `-c` option on `ps`.

Because my app comes in several flavors and versions which each contain different helpers, and because users may have multiple installations, and because of the sometimes strange behavior of Launch Services, for self-testing and diagnostic purposes, I would like to get the path to the running helper's package or executable.

Why does `ps` give the bundle identifier instead?  How can I get the path?

Answer (score 1):

A program can a) rewrite the memory pointed to by `argv` and the strings it points to, and/or b) call `setprogname()`.

I seem to recall that `setprogname()` does **not** affect the output of `ps`, but rewriting `argv` does. I could have that backwards, though. I know that [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) [does both](https://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/kernel32/process.c?v=wine-3.19#1289) and affects the command that `ps` sees.

Comment: Wow, that is wild, Ken.  My helper app certainly does not touch `argv` nor call `setprogname()`.  However, this is interesting, because certainly such manipulations are somehow within the powers of Apple's *launchd*.

Comment: Launchd might do it. So might XPC in the launched service, somehow.